# Copy file to Sharepoint-share fails unless user connects to Sharepoint server for the first time

Tags: c#, sharepoint, unc, file-copying, system.io.file

I have a strange behaviour when I try to use a C# program to copy local files to a Sharepoint Server using UNC paths provided by Sharepoint to access the file system. First of all, my user has all the privileges required to access that specific Sharepoint-folder.

This is what my operation basically looks like:

```
string targetSharepointPath = @"\\team.mycompany.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\team\wmscompanydep\Software Releases\MyToolConfig"
System.IO.File.Copy(sourcePath, targetSharepointPath, false);
```

This fails with an error "The network path was not found."

As soon as I copy the path above and paste it into WIndows File Explorer (*not* internet explorer, this is simply an UNC path), everything works.

So my assumption is, that in the background, Windows explorer does a little bit more. But what? I do not have to enter any credentials, the targetSharepointPath simply works in explorer, and as soon as this was entered once, it also works in my C# program. Until I restart my system, I have to repeat that step. Why, and how can I achieve that programatically? I work with UNC paths on "normal" Windows servers a lot, and once the user has rights I do not need any additional authentication.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To connect to a `Sharepoint` you need a windows service called `WebClient`.

When you open that link from the Explorer, it will make sure that the service is started. That might be the reason why you're able to access the `Sharepoint` from your app after you opened the link in Explorer.

You can make sure that your clients have that `service` started automatically to achieve it.

Or you can try starting the service from you code in this way. (You might need admin privileges for this)

```
using (ServiceController service= new ServiceController("WebClient"))
    {

        if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
        {

            service.Start();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15));
            //Check status here by calling service.Status and proceed with your code.
        }
        else
        {
          //proceed with your code as the service is up and running
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used this several times now, and it does the job, good answer, thank you!

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. I was getting a network path not found error. One note on the code above is that it needs a reference to System.ServiceProcess.dll. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx